# css flexbox как разделить div на две колонки

Tags: css3, flexbox

Подскажите как сделать что-то подобное с помощью flexbox[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 270px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  column-count: 2
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно чтобе div который не помещается в первую колонку разделяло на 2 колонки как на картинке:

[image]

Comment: Тогда про flex забудьте, он не даст Вам это сделать.

Comment: а как ето можна сделать?

Comment: Я выше исправил ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: не за что, удачи